# "chrome.notifications.clear" does not clear from the tray menu while it is open?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications, google-chrome-app

I have my notifications configured to remove themselves after pressing one of the buttons included on them..

The issue I am running into is that when I attempt to remove the notification using `chrome.notifications.clear` (when the notification has been minimized to the tray, and the expanded tray view is being used), the notification will remain displayed in the tray menu until the menu has been closed. Upon re-opening the tray menu the notification will be gone.

Is there a different method that would need to be used to clear that item while it is being displayed in the tray, or maybe is this just a bug with chrome?

(testing on OS X by the way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known/acknowledged bug in Chrome: [#335918](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=335918)

I am also affected by it, but to my knowledge there is no alternative.

Comment: Ah, I had a feeling this would be the case.. Thanks for the heads up!